# Why my Paginate firestore wont load data only based on my itemPerPage int

Tags: flutter

I'm using paginate firestore to show data for my app, I limited it to show only 5 data and the other will be loaded again after user reach the fifth data. The problem is the limitation didn't work and it show all of the data (30++) causing my app performance to be really heavy.

What cause this problem ? Here's my code

```
  PaginateFirestore(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      isLive: true,
      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      query: selectedQueryFinding,
      key: ValueKey('$selectedFindingLocation-'),
      itemsPerPage: 5,
      itemBuilderType: PaginateBuilderType.listView,
      itemBuilder: (context, documentSnapshots, index) {
        var data = documentSnapshots[index].data() as Map;

        DevMode.log('Paginate data ${data['title']}');

        return FutureBuilder(
            future: loadTemuanData(data: data),
            builder: (BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ReusableTemuanCard(
                  temuanData: snapshot.data,
                  temuanId: documentSnapshots[index]
                      .id,
                );
              }
              else {
                return const SizedBox.shrink();
              }
            }
        );
      }
  ),
```